# C Shell Scripting - append to the end of a file name

Tags: scripting, csh

So I'm taking in a number of files, and I wish to copy them to a directory and store them with an added file extension, say ".copy".

I'm not really sure what command I can use to append something to the end of a file, is it simpler than I am thinking or do I need a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you plan to do this using a loop or are you trying to find a one-liner?  If you have a file `$f`, you can just say `$f.copy` for the appended version.

Comment: planning on a loop, how would I use this to actually copy the files?

Comment: `cp $f dir/$f.copy`.  See T.Rob's answer for a one-liner version using `xargs`, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1 | xargs -I{} cp {} {}.copy
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1
file1.txt
file1.txt.copy
file2.txt
file2.txt.copy
file3.txt
file3.txt.copy
```

Depending on your platform you may need to vary the syntax for xargs a bit.  I have seen it use `-i{}` and `-I{}` but the uppercase variant seems to be more common.  You could of course specify a full path name preceding the `{}.copy` file name so that the files end up in a different directory.

If you need to do a little more than a one-liner, there's also this:

```
ls -1 | {
    while read _file; do
        echo Copying $_file to $_file.copy
        cp $_file $_file.copy
    done
}
```

You can put any number of lines in the while loop.  For example, you can copy the same file to a dozen different destination directories or suffixes.  If you just paste it in you don't need to make a script out of it.  The result looks like this:

```
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1 | {
>     while read _file; do
>         echo Copying $_file to $_file.copy
>         cp $_file $_file.copy
>     done
> }
Copying file1.txt to file1.txt.copy
Copying file2.txt to file2.txt.copy
Copying file3.txt to file3.txt.copy
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files> ls -1
file1.txt
file1.txt.copy
file2.txt
file2.txt.copy
file3.txt
file3.txt.copy
fteadmin@linux-wmq-ams:~/files>
```